# ui-gmap-polyline fit="true" doesn't zoom in the path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working with ui-gmap-polyline and I can't zoom the path I draw in the map.
What I read is that the property 'fit' should do that, but unless I center the map, it doesn't even render map, but if I center the map of course it is center in that point not in the path.

Can someone help me to see what I am doing wrong in the code?

```
      <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
        <ui-gmap-polyline path="vm.gpxCoordinates.path" draggable="false" geodesic="true" stroke="vm.gpxCoordinates.stroke" fit="true"></ui-gmap-polyline>
       </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

In my controller I have

```
    vm.gpxCoordinates =
       {
           id: 1,
           path: [],
           stroke: { color: '#6060FB', weight: 3 }
       };

    function activate() {
        uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function () {
            vm.mapInitializationComplete = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < vm.map.gpx.length; ++i) {
                vm.gpxCoordinates.path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(vm.map.gpx[i].latitude, vm.map.gpx[i].longitude));
            }
            //$scope.map = vm.map.position;
        });
    }
```

Well with this code the map doesn't even render, there isn't any error in the console. If I uncomment //$scope.map = vm.map.position; the map renders, but it is centered in that point, but what I need is it to be automatically centered in the path of the polyline.

Shouldn't the fit="true" in the directive be enough to center in the map, do I have to center it in another way or am I missing something here?